Why does my Google Cloud Function throw "Memory Limit of 256 MiB exceed" as an error but still it does the job?
I have a Google Cloud Function that has a Python 3.9 runtime. It is essentially an ETL script that extracts data from Google BigQuery and loads into the MySQL, triggered by an HTTP call to the endpoint.
There has been no issue with the code. When I was testing on our staging project. It was working fine. Even, on the production environment. It works fine but looking at the logs, this is what I see: 
For the looks of it, Cloud Functions start with full memory but still manages to do the job. I don't quite understand how this happens.
My function doesn't do anything crazy. It just does the following:

extract()
load()
execute_some_sql().

But I do import some libraries, so I am not sure if this is causing the issue. These are following libraries from the requirement.txt:
pandas==2.2.1
pandas-gbq==0.21.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.27
google-auth==2.28.1
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.0
functions-framework==3.5.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.18.3

I tried going through google documentation for RAM limitations for Google Cloud Functions. It didn't provide me with enough information to identify what was going wrong.

it clearly tells you that the memory limit is exceeded.

@D.L shouldn't the GCF instance then terminate by itself then?

The error seems like a warning message as your function is doing the job. However, verify that you are not leaking any memory in your code. If there is no memory leak as your functions is working fine Contact support to get the root cause.

Increase the instance memory to 512 MB. Run tests. If you see a memory error again, then you have a memory leak to fix. Otherwise, leave it at 512 MB and move on to your next problem. You can simulate the Cloud Run memory limits using Docker on your desktop. Then you can debug and test using your desktop tools.

Get 1 minute of your General Log recorded. Count the number of CONNECT's in the log and count the number of QUIT's in the log. If the numbers are significantly different maybe someone forgot to CLOSE the connection when finished with the client request.

@NirshadNijam You may find this url helpful -
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips
04/09/2024 if you think Google is eating your RAM,
see about page 2 for Always delete temporary files
The next sentence describes a Console use to view 'memory used' by function.
